# Issue with adding main() to a Java class

Tags: java, frameworks, compiler-errors

Newb to Java and can't seem to find the proper answer to this somewhat simple question on Google.

I'm using a genetic programming framework for some research, and have been trying to customize their examples for my needs.  Defining the main function is left to the user, so that is what I am trying to do.

There is a pre-existing class that I am trying to make a runnable file.  It extends a higher-level class to call other functionality.

Here is the code that I am having issues with (its from a built-in example):

```
public class Multiplexer extends GPModel {
    public Multiplexer(final int noInputBits) {
      ...
    }

    ...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Multiplexer(6).run();
    }  
}
```

This is the error I am seeing.  I am using NetBeans 7.3.1 with JDK 1.7.

> Error: Main method not found in class org.epochx.gp.model.Multiplexer,
>   please define the main method as:    public static void main(String[]
>   args) Java Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

It should be fairly trivial....I've created other classes with a main function and haven't run into this issue...it seems to be only in the pre-existing classes defined within the framework that have this problem.

---

**Edit**

Sorry, the encapsulating class was public already, forgot to mention that.

---

**Edit2**  The full source, as requested...(epochx.org, if anybody is interested, v1.4.1)

```
package org.epochx.gp.model;

import java.util.*;

import org.epochx.epox.*;
import org.epochx.epox.bool.*;
import org.epochx.epox.lang.IfFunction;
import org.epochx.gp.representation.GPCandidateProgram;
import org.epochx.representation.CandidateProgram;
import org.epochx.tools.util.BoolUtils;

/**
 * GP model for the multiplexer problems.
 * 
 * <h4>Multiplexer problem</h4>
 * 
 * Given n binary inputValues, a program that solves the majority problem will
 * return true in all circumstances where a majority of the inputValues are true
 * (or 1), and return false whenever there is not a majority of true values.
 */
public class Multiplexer extends GPModel {

    // The names of the inputValues used in the grammar.
    private final Variable[] variables;

    // The boolean input sequences.
    private final boolean[][] inputValues;

    // No input bits.
    private int noAddressBits;
    private int noDataBits;

    /**
     * Constructs a Multiplexer model for the given number of inputs.
     * 
     * @param noInputBits the number of inputs the multiplexer problem should be
     *        for
     */
    public Multiplexer(final int noInputBits) {
        // Generate the input sequences.
        inputValues = BoolUtils.generateBoolSequences(noInputBits);

        // Calculate number of address/data bits.
        setBitSizes(noInputBits);

        // Define functions.
        final List<Node> syntax = new ArrayList<Node>();
        syntax.add(new IfFunction());
        syntax.add(new AndFunction());
        syntax.add(new OrFunction());
        syntax.add(new NotFunction());

        // Define terminal variables.
        variables = new Variable[noInputBits];
        // Add address inputs.
        for (int i = 0; i < noAddressBits; i++) {
            variables[i] = new Variable("a" + i, Boolean.class);
            syntax.add(variables[i]);
        }
        // Add data inputs.
        for (int i = noAddressBits; i < noInputBits; i++) {
            variables[i] = new Variable("d" + i, Boolean.class);
            syntax.add(variables[i]);
        }

        setSyntax(syntax);
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the fitness score for the given program. The fitness of a
     * program for the majority problem is calculated by evaluating it
     * using each of the possible sets of input values. There are
     * <code>2^noInputBits</code> possible sets of inputs. The fitness of the
     * program is the quantity of those input sequences that the program
     * returned an incorrect response for. That is, a fitness value of
     * <code>0.0</code> indicates the program responded correctly for every
     * possible set of input values.
     * 
     * @param p {@inheritDoc}
     * @return the calculated fitness for the given program.
     */
    @Override
    public double getFitness(final CandidateProgram p) {
        final GPCandidateProgram program = (GPCandidateProgram) p;

        double score = 0;

        // Execute on all possible inputs.
        for (final boolean[] in: inputValues) {

            // Set the variables.
            for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
                variables[i].setValue(in[i]);
            }

            if ((Boolean) program.evaluate() == multiplex(in)) {
                score++;
            }
        }

        return inputValues.length - score;
    }

    /*
     * Calculate and set the number of address and data bits.
     */
    private void setBitSizes(final int noInputBits) {
        noAddressBits = 1;
        while (true) {
            noDataBits = (int) Math.pow(2, noAddressBits);

            if ((noAddressBits + noDataBits) == noInputBits) {
                break;
            }

            noAddressBits++;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Calculate what the correct response should be for the given inputs.
     */
    private Boolean multiplex(final boolean[] vars) {
        // Calculate which data position to use.
        int dataPosition = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < noAddressBits; i++) {
            if (vars[i]) {
                dataPosition += Math.pow(2, i);
            }
        }

        return vars[noAddressBits + dataPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getReturnType() {
        return Boolean.class;
    }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Multiplexer(6).run();
    }  
}
```

Comment: clean and build... close and open the ide again

Comment: Can you provide the full code for your class?

Comment: @nachokk: done...no luck

Comment: @clement: code posted

Comment: create a new class , Test.java and make the main method there..

Comment: Try running the class from the terminal, without using Netbeans.

Comment: @nachokk: that got rid of the error...and pointed me towards a shortcoming in the example...turn it into an answer and i'll accept!

Comment: in my pc run, with netbeans.. no output but running succesful you don't by the way you forget to import `import org.epochx.gp.model.GPModel;`

Comment: @nachokk: the reason i was not getting output was that i wasn't fully setting up the genetic program properly...your comment regarding creating a new class and calling it from there worked just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and for me worked.. try to clean and build... or easier create a new class Test and put the main there.

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE is probably still referencing some old jar or class files.  Do a clean/build/refresh (I don't use NetBeans, but whatever the equivalent is) and your changes should register.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I think I've figured it out!

Your source code is defining a class called `Multiplexer` in `org.epochx.gp.model`.  [But there is already a class called `Multiplexer` in `org.epochx.gp.model`](http://www.epochx.org/javadoc/1.4/org/epochx/gp/model/Multiplexer.html)!

So what *is most likely* happening is that your build classpath and your launch classpath are different, and in the launch case the IDE's launcher is finding the standard `Multiplexer` first ... and that one doesn't have a `main` method at all.

> Lesson #1: Don't declare your classes in other peoples' packages!
>
> Lesson #1a: Don't make your changes in other peoples code ... unless you have to.  (And in this case, you don't.)

---

(Original answer ...)

I think that the problem is that your `Multiplexer` class is not `public`.  While the `java` command does not require this, it *looks* like the problem is that the IDE itself cannot identify an entry point in the class ...

If that is not it, then another possibility is that your IDE has gotten out of sync with the filesystem (or something like than) and needs restarting.

Another possibility was that `String` in your source code was referring to something other than `java.lang.String`.  But unless you are using some new version of `org.epochx` that defines its own `String` class, I don't think that is possible.  (And the `org.epochx` javadocs on the web don't include a `String` class.)

The only other possibility I can think of is "funky characters".  Perhaps one of the characters in your `main` identifier is not a Roman / Latin letter.  There are certain Unicode characters that *look like* Latin letters ... but aren't.  There is more info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack#Homographs_in_internationalized_domain_names) (though in a different context ...).

---

If all else fails, try running your application from the command line using the `java` command to see if that makes any difference.  If not, try using `javap` to examine the ".class" file and find out what the signature of that `main` method *really* is.

Comment: I thought the same, but just wrote a little program and my non-public class ran with main just fine.

Comment: That may be true. I'll clarify. For vanilla java (wrote class in vim, compiled and executed on command line) the class does not have to be public. :)  If Netbeans requires it (not going to install it just for this) then I would consider that a bug in netbeans, which may very well be a valid answer to this question, but until he posts the full source or someone else validates in netbeans we won't know...

Comment: good catch, but that was just a typo from my end....it was public and i forgot to type it in

Comment: @StephenC: i wasn't defining a new multiplexer class, i was simply trying to add a main function to the pre-existing class in the package you described

Comment: @espais - **Well you shouldn't do that!!!**  What you should do is create your own subclass of that class ... in your own package.  Either way, the most likely cause of the problem is the same ... the IDE launcher is looking at the wrong "version" of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try making your class (`Multiplexer`) public.

Comment: the class does not need to be public. I verified with a test class of my own.